# MySQL IF returning nothing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do some optimisation, currently post mysql work is done on the results to set a new paramter `$class_subject`... so i am trying get this already calculated in mysql...

```
SELECT
     class_grade.results                as results,
     subjects.subject                   as subject,
     subjects_pseudonyms.pseudonym      as pseudonym,
     IF( subjects_pseudonyms.pseudonym = null, subjects.subject, subjects_pseudonyms.pseudonym ) as class_subject
 FROM
     class_grade
 INNER JOIN class               ON class_grade.class_ID         = class.class_ID
 INNER JOIN subjects            ON class.subject_ID             = subjects.a_ID
 LEFT JOIN  subjects_pseudonyms ON class.subject_pseudonym_ID   = subjects_pseudonyms.a_ID
 WHERE
     class_grade.teacher_ID     = :teacher_id AND
     class_grade.class_ID       = :current_class_ID AND
     class_grade.report_set_ID  = :report_set_ID AND
     class_grade.student_ID     = :current_student_ID
```

In the above query the `pseudonym` might be null, if so I am attempting to set a new variable `class_subject` to be either `subject` or `pseudonym`...

The query runs fine, a results example is:

```
[results] => 71
[subject] => Law
[pseudonym] => 
[class_subject] =>
```

The problem is, the `class_subject` is not being populated..

Is there something wrong with my IF() cond?

Thanks,
John

Comment: have you tried with condition subjects_pseudonyms.pseudonym IS null ? (so IS instead of =)

Comment: I am not totally sure i follow, do you mean only select the `subjects.subject` if `subjects_pseudonyms.pseudonym` is null?

Comment: just replace the = sign with IS keyword in the condition, that was my suggestion.

Comment: :) Awesome, thank you that worked a treat! ha, I was so close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` or `ISNULL()`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

> ISNULL() can be used instead of = to test whether a value is NULL.
>   (Comparing a value to NULL using = always yields **false**.)